# ionic, NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to false

Tags: ionic3

Can someone let me know how I can enable `AppTransportSecurity` in ionic 3/4? Also, I am unable to set `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `false`. When I set this to `false` in the info.plist file and build the app, it gets reset to `true`.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add in your config.xml file inside `<platform name="ios">`

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSAppTransportSecurity">
        <dict>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <false />
        </dict>
</edit-config>
```

You can verify it by navigating to platform/ios/`yourAppName`/`youAppName`-Info.plist

[image]